# How to update first n records in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Is there any query available to update only first n records of SQLite DB ..?

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer assumes that the primary key identifier is starting at 1. This would not be the case if rows have been deleted.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html states:
"If SQLite is built with the SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT compile-time option then the syntax of the UPDATE statement is extended with optional ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses..."

In this case, you can use this simple query:

```
UPDATE table SET columns = 'value' WHERE 1 LIMIT n ORDER BY identifier ASC
```

The other clause might not be needed based on the default ordering scheme.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a sequential int identifier, `UPDATE table SET columns = 'value' WHERE identifier <= n`

Comment: You can likely use the [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)